# How do I make a shadow appear under the navigation bar when I scroll down the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, shadow

I have a navigation bar on my website and I want to set a shadow when the user starts scrolling down the page.

How do I make a shadow appear under the navigation bar when I scroll down the page ?

So if the user scrolls down the page, the shadow should appear immediately.

Maybe it's possible to do this with just CSS.

```css
.site-header {
  z-index: 111;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 75rem) {
  .site-header__fixable .site-header__inner {
    box-shadow: -36px 1px 36px rgb(0 0 0 / 8%);
  }
}
```

```html
<header id="header" class="site-header" data-drupal-selector="site-header" role="banner" data-once="navigation">

  <div class="site-header__fixable" data-drupal-selector="site-header-fixable">
    <div class="site-header__initial">
      <button class="sticky-header-toggle" data-drupal-selector="sticky-header-toggle" role="switch" aria-controls="site-header__inner" aria-label="Sticky header" aria-checked="false">
        <span class="sticky-header-toggle__icon">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div id="site-header__inner" class="site-header__inner" data-drupal-selector="site-header-inner">
      <div class="container site-header__inner__container">

        <div class="header-nav-overlay" data-drupal-selector="header-nav-overlay"></div>

        <div class="mobile-buttons" data-drupal-selector="mobile-buttons">
          <button class="mobile-nav-button" data-drupal-selector="mobile-nav-button" aria-label="Main Menu" aria-controls="header-nav" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="mobile-nav-button__label">Menu</span>
            <span class="mobile-nav-button__icon"></span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <div id="header-nav" class="header-nav" data-drupal-selector="header-nav">

          <nav id="block-subtheme-olivero-main-menu" class="primary-nav block block-menu navigation menu--main" aria-labelledby="block-subtheme-olivero-main-menu-menu" role="navigation">

            <h2 class="visually-hidden block__title" id="block-subtheme-olivero-main-menu-menu">Main navigation</h2>

            <ul class="menu primary-nav__menu primary-nav__menu--level-1" data-drupal-selector="primary-nav-menu--level-1" data-once="olivero-automatic-mobile-nav">

              <li class="primary-nav__menu-item primary-nav__menu-item--link primary-nav__menu-item--level-1 primary-nav__menu-item--has-children" data-drupal-selector="primary-nav-menu-item-has-children">

                <a href="/culture-geek" class="primary-nav__menu-link primary-nav__menu-link--link primary-nav__menu-link--level-1 primary-nav__menu-link--has-children" data-drupal-selector="primary-nav-menu-link-has-children" data-drupal-link-system-path="taxonomy/term/14">
                  <span class="primary-nav__menu-link-inner primary-nav__menu-link-inner--level-1">Culture geek</span>
                </a>

                <button class="primary-nav__button-toggle" data-drupal-selector="primary-nav-submenu-toggle-button" aria-controls="primary-menu-item-1" aria-expanded="false">
                      <span class="visually-hidden">sous-navigation Culture geek</span>
                      <span class="icon--menu-toggle"></span>
                    </button>

                <span data-drupal-selector="primary-nav-menu-" class="primary-nav__menu-"></span>

                <ul class="menu primary-nav__menu primary-nav__menu--level-2" data-drupal-selector="primary-nav-menu--level-2" id="primary-menu-item-1">

                  <li class="primary-nav__menu-item primary-nav__menu-item--link primary-nav__menu-item--level-2">

                    <a href="/crypto" class="primary-nav__menu-link primary-nav__menu-link--link primary-nav__menu-link--level-2" data-drupal-link-system-path="taxonomy/term/2"> <span class="primary-nav__menu-link-inner primary-nav__menu-link-inner--level-2">Crypto</span>
                    </a>

                  </li>

                  <li class="primary-nav__menu-item primary-nav__menu-item--link primary-nav__menu-item--level-2">

                    <a href="/unboxing" class="primary-nav__menu-link primary-nav__menu-link--link primary-nav__menu-link--level-2" data-drupal-link-system-path="taxonomy/term/3"> <span class="primary-nav__menu-link-inner primary-nav__menu-link-inner--level-2">Unboxing</span>
                    </a>

                  </li>

                  <li class="primary-nav__menu-item primary-nav__menu-item--link primary-nav__menu-item--level-2">

                    <a href="/vie-pratique" class="primary-nav__menu-link primary-nav__menu-link--link primary-nav__menu-link--level-2" data-drupal-link-system-path="taxonomy/term/1"> <span class="primary-nav__menu-link-inner primary-nav__menu-link-inner--level-2">Vie pratique</span>
                    </a>

                  </li>

                  <li class="primary-nav__menu-item primary-nav__menu-item--link primary-nav__menu-item--level-2">

                    <a href="/securite-et-confidentialite" class="primary-nav__menu-link primary-nav__menu-link--link primary-nav__menu-link--level-2" data-drupal-link-system-path="taxonomy/term/4"> <span class="primary-nav__menu-link-inner primary-nav__menu-link-inner--level-2">Sécurité et confidentialité</span>
                    </a>

                  </li>

                  <li class="primary-nav__menu-item primary-nav__menu-item--link primary-nav__menu-item--level-2">

                    <a href="/ambiance" class="primary-nav__menu-link primary-nav__menu-link--link primary-nav__menu-link--level-2" data-drupal-link-system-path="taxonomy/term/5"> <span class="primary-nav__menu-link-inner primary-nav__menu-link-inner--level-2">Ambiance</span>
                    </a>

                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: You seem to have an extra closing div tag up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `window.onscroll` is not sufficient if you want shadow appear under the navigation. Even if you scroll horizontally the `window.onscroll` will trigger.

So must use `scrollTop` method. This method sets or returns the vertical scrollbar position for the selected elements.

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 10 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 10) {
    document.getElementById("header").style.boxShadow = "0 8px 6px -6px #000";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("header").style.boxShadow = "none";
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But it fires late. Is it possible to trigger it from the first pixel ? There is a problem, if I open the menu, it goes back to the top of the page.

Comment: It is not triggering late. It is checking whether you scrolled **50 px** or more. You can just reduce it.
Try Changing : 
`document.body.scrollTop > 10 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 10`

Comment: Thank you, is your code pure JS or Jquery? Because drupal 9 no longer supports jquery and wants pure JS.

Comment: This code is pure JS

Answer (score 0):

I think this needs JavaScript.
Try to add this **under** the header.

```
<script>
window.onscroll = function () {
document.getElementById('header').style.boxShadow = "0px 2.5px 5px silver"
    if (document.documentElement.scrolTop < 10) {
document.getElementById('header').style.boxShadow = "0px 2.5px 5px #ffffff00"
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's better, but when I go back to the top, the shadow remains. Normally it should disappear at the top and only appear when I start to descend.